# File not found: Error for Contents.json when running Xamarin App using a Mac on my network

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When trying to run the Xamarin.IOS project of my mobile application I get the following error.

`File not found: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/665113b8e3040a55db5fc43a003035bd/NLogLogger.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json`

Q1.) I have another project which runs successfully, and that projects checks for the Contents.json file in the directory:

`/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/OtherApp.iOS/665113b8e3040a55db5fc43a003035bd/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json`

This leads me to think that the issue is coming from Xamarin looking for Contents.json in the wrong directory, any idea how to get it to look in the proper location? (I think this could fix the problem)

Q2. Does anyone understand this error and how to fix it, I have been stuck with this for quite a while now.

**Note: I have been focused on the Xamarin.Android for this project and this is the first time I am running it the Xamarin.IOS version.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue by excluding the `NLogLogger.xcassets` (which was located in `Asseets.xcassets`) from my project and then deleting it.

I also had to make changes to the file `MyApp.iOS.csproj`, and remove the `<ItemGroup>` that specified the `NLogLogger.xcassets` directory (and some other items in the xml that were unnecessary). **Rebuilding did not fix this initially because I did not exclude them from the project.**

I cleaned, and rebuilt my project after this and it works.

Answer (score 24):

I was able to solve it this way:

1. Right click your ios project > unload project > and edit the csproj file.
2. Scroll down and delete the following inside the csproj:

**.csproj:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\Contents.json">
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\LaunchImages.launchimage\Contents.json">
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
</ItemGroup>
```

3. Reload csproj.
4. Clean
5. Rebuild

Comment: Yes, this is the solution!! Thank you very much! I had 2 ressource catalogs and need to delete the one with Assets.xcassets

Comment: When I make this change, my app will build. But now I can no longer archive my app for upload to the store. Apple keeps saying that I am missing my app icon.

Comment: Eventhough it is present in the assets? @Dave

Answer (score 1):

The `Contents.json` file is automatically created when you add a new `xxx.xcassets` to your iOS project. This usually happen if you forget to include it to your project.

You can check if the `Contents.json` file exist by right click `NLogLogger.xcassets` --> `Reveal in Finder` and then you can see the `Contents.json` file in the folder.

What I recommend you to do is creating a new `xxx.xcassets` and readd your images there, then clean and rebuild project.( Remember to delete the `NLogLogger.xcassets)`

Comment: Hello, so part of the problem is that I have no NLogLogger.xcassets in any of my directories (Within the Library/builds on my Mac or within the IOS project on my windows machine.) but for some reason, it is still looking for the AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json within this directory, do you have any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Try to delete the obj/bin folder in xxx.project and xxx.ios.project, clean and rebuild again. In your windows machine, you can click the show all files button(which is located below solution explorer) to check if the file exist.